# CF7 delay submission until variable changes

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I have a CF7 setup in place with a Google sheet and Paypal integration.

Once the submit button of a form is pressed, two things happen:

1) the entered data is being send to my spreadsheet

2) the client is being redirected to a PayPal payment portal

After this, the data from the spreadsheet is being processed using a custom Google script and the client will receive an automated e-mail with a download link to their file once it finished processing. Since the data is being submitted before the PayPal redirection, the file will be processed and send to the client even if he/she doesn't complete the Payment.

Is there a way to delay the CF7 submission until after Payment has been processed? If so, how would I go about this?

As an alternative, I was thinking to delay the processing of the files within my Google script until a payment status has been updated. In order to do this though, I would need send a PayPal transfer ID to my Google sheet using the CF7 form submission (to identify which submission has been payed).

I would prefer the first method, of delaying the submission to the spreadsheet until the payment status has been completed. I have no clue if this is even possible however.

For the second option I was looking in to CF7 custom shortcodes, in order to get a payment identifier to go with my submission data. I tried adding the following code to the functions.php for testing purposes, but by doing so my page come up with a critical error, so I've removed that for now.

```
$paymentID= 'placeholderString';

wpcf7_add_shortcode('input_test', function( $tag ) { return '<input name="'.$tag['basetype'].'" value= '$paymentID' />' });
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

With kind regards,
Danny